# Find the value of $a$ if $x^2+y^2=axy$ has positive integer solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find the value of $a$ if $x^2+y^2=axy$ has positive integer solution.

---

My try:
Let g.c.d of $x$ and $y$ is $d$ i.e.$(x,y)=d$ and let $x=dx',y=dy'.$
Then $x'^2+y'^2=ax'y'$
I am stuck here.The answer given is $a=2$.I do not understand how.Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x^2+y^2-axy=0$. Then $x\mid y^2$ and $y\mid x^2$ in positive integers.
From this we see that $x$ and $y$ have the same prime divisors, possibly with different multiplicity. But then the equation implies $x=y$, hence $x^2(a-2)=0$. Since $x>0$ we obtain $a=2$.

Comment: I did not understand why $x\mid y^2$ and $y\mid x^2$ in positive integers.Any reason?@DietrichBurde

Comment: $x^2=axy-y^2=y(ax-y)$, hence $y\mid x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=a$. Assume $gcd(x,y)=d$ and $x=du, y=dv$ where $(u,v)=1.$ So we get 
$\frac{u^2+v^2}{uv}=a$. Now, $u|u^2+v^2$, so $u|v^2$ and so $u|v$. By similar argument, we have $v|u$. But $(u,v)=1$ so we must have both $u,v$ either $+1$ or 
$-1.[u,v$ both have the same sign because $a$ is positive$].$ In both cases, we have $a=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\frac{y}{x}$, the equation becomes $m+\frac{1}{m}=a$ and $m^2-ma+1=0$. In order to get rationals for $m$ discriminant must be a square; That is $a^2-4=k^2$. Only possible when $a=2$.